# Unable to find a WebElement when invoking an ant job in Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I was trying to invoke an `ant job` in `Jenkins`, it failed since some web elements were not found (I find these elements by their ID). However, I can build the ant successfully in Eclipse without this issue. I was using `Jenkins-1.651.3` in Window7.

```
public class SendEmail 

WebDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver();

@Parameters("url")
@Test
public void openHomePage(String url) throws Exception
{
    browser.get("https://exmail.qq.com/");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "openHomePage" )
public void openLoginPage() throws Exception
{
  WebElement loginButton = browser.findElement(By.linkText("登录"));
  loginButton.click();
}

@Parameters({"username","password"})
@Test(dependsOnMethods = "openLoginPage" )
public void authentication(String username, String password) throws   Exception
{
  WebElement userNameField = browser.findElement(By.id("inputuin"));
  WebElement passwordField = browser.findElement(By.id("pp"));
  WebElement checkbox = browser.findElement(By.id("ss"));
  WebElement buttonLogin = browser.findElement(By.id("btlogin"));
  checkbox.click();
  userNameField.sendKeys(username);
  passwordField.sendKeys(password);
  buttonLogin.submit();
}
```

[image: error message]

Comment: Post code. Otherwise this is about as vague and unanswerable as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Add some implicit wait after creating driver instance:

```
WebDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver();
browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And also add some explicit wait before before finding username input field like

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("inputuin"))));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I can run this job successfully in an opened Internet(Public Net), but Intranet. Not sure whether this is a network problem